# What is the female equivalent of playboy?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

I want to know the female equivalent of playboy person, Can we say playgirl? and can we use it for a person aged over 25.

Comment: Google for "playboy antonyms"

Comment: You should describe the qualities of the "opposite" person you envision. Your question is like saying "What is the opposite of an engineer?"

Comment: Are you asking for the "opposite" of playboy, or the female equivalent of playboy....very different ideas.

Comment: As user3169 notes, *playboy* has many different aspects and connotations: male, probably wealthy, probably a hedonist (and thus quite possibly a drunk, or sexually promiscuous, or an epicure), and likely to be young or emotionally immature. What aspect are you looking for the "opposite" of?

Comment: Playboy suggests a number of behaviours that are mildly disapproved of fir men but strongly disapproved of for women. If such a word exists, it will not be a pleasant word.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/playgirl

Answer (score 3):

The best equivalent I can think of is a [**playgirl**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/playgirl) which seems very close in meaning to [playboy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/playboy).

Yes, you can use it for females older than 25.
See also [coquette](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coquette), 
[minx](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Minx)

For a woman who's mature but still likes fooling around, [cougar](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cougar) is a common slang word. See also [sugar momma](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sugar+Momma).

Answer (score 1):

A close equivalent is **"Belle of the Ball"**, the woman who men find having an interesting personality and attractive at an upscale social event. A present-day novel could have the playboy talk to the **Belle of Ball**, yet both words are a bit from an earlier time.
 I just want to add that the word "playboy" originated as meaning "boys who actors on stage" and evolved by the 1960's to be the word for men who were popular with attractive women from the upper class. "Belle of the Ball" tends to represent attractive women from the upper class, making it the probable equivalent to playboy.